# YOLO & Darknet - Training on a custom dataset to detect a specific class and ignore other classes

Tags: yolo, darknet, darkflow

When training a custom dataset using YOLO and darknet, suppose available data is annotated with 3 classes,
**voc.names**

```
cat
dog
bird
```

So, the **.txt** files will be in the format of

```
1 0.587 0.576 0.361 0.415
0 0.205 0.803 0.166 0.206
0 0.181 0.597 0.166 0.206
2 0.417 0.857 0.166 0.206
```

which means cat is class 0, dog - class 1, bird - class 2

If I want to train the model to detect only dog(class 1) and ignore remaining classes, how to do it? Can I change the **voc.names** file in the following manner i.e. leave the 1st and 3rd line empty

```
<assume empty line>
dog
<assume empty line>
```

If the above process is wrong, is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the model to detect all classes, but only draw the **dog** boxes, you can just add an if condition before the drawing function. But if you want to reduce the number of classes from 3 to 1, you should take some other steps:

- You should change the number of classes in the code everywhere that it is mentioned from 3 to 1. For example, in each of the three yolo layers. Also change number of maximum batches which is `number_of_classes*2000` (divide by 3).
- change number of filters in each of the conv layers before yolo layers. By default it is `number_of_filters=(classes + 5)x3`
- change **voc.names** to a file with 1 line (dog) without empty lines.
- change number of classes in **voc.data**

It would help if you could post related part of the code or a link.

Comment: "change number of classes in voc.data" - But the problem is the annotated files(.txt) has 'dog' as class 1. If we mention only dog class in voc.names, it throws an error. In darkflow, if we mention a particular class in 'labels.txt', it automatically ignores the remaining classes from the annotated xml files and we can make the necessary changes in .cfg as you mentioned above. I think there is no such functionality in darknet, we might have to edit .txt files to contain only necessary classes. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to train your network with dog class only, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898577/how-to-reduce-number-of-classes-in-yolov3-files) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove other classes. It could be a solution :

```
import numpy as np
import os

# Specific class
class_remaining = 1
# Dataset's folder name
folder = "Dataset"

# Browse the dataset
for file in os.listdir(folder):
    # Get the data from txt file as numpy array
    data = np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter=" ")
    # Filter the array
    filter = data[:, 0] == class_remaining
    # Save the filter array in txt file
    np.savetxt(file, data[filter], newline='\n', fmt='%1.3f')
```