# How to improve Alturos.YOLO performance on webcam?

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv, yolo

I am using Alturos.YOLO with Emgu CV 3.2 (World.dll) in a C# WPF Application. I am testing this app on an 8GB RAM. But, it is VERY slow. I don't know what seems to be the problem. Here is my code:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var img = capture.QueryFrame();
    videoViewer.Source = ToBitmapSource(img);
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    img.Bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
    var _items = yolo.Detect(memoryStream.ToArray()).ToList();
    var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img.Bitmap);
    var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightGreen);

    foreach (var item in _items)
    {
        var x = item.X;
        var y = item.Y;
        var width = item.Width;
        var height = item.Height;
        var type = item.Type;  // class name of the object
        var rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
        var pen = new Pen(Color.LightGreen, 6);
        var point = new System.Drawing.Point(x + width / 2, y + height / 2);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        graphics.DrawString($"{item.Type} : {item.Height} * {item.Width}", new Font("Arial", 23f), brush, point);
        MessageBox.Show(type);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of two things, or both, either reducing the number of classes in your YOLO database to the objects you target only, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898577/how-to-reduce-number-of-classes-in-yolov3-files) is some details, or try to use GPU to accelerate detection using [CUDA C++](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads), but you must own a NVidia card. These two methods worked for me and reduced detection time greatly.