# is Is there any way to annotate or label multiple person images on person single class dataset. for YOLOv3?

Tags: computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, yolo

I want to detect only person detection by using YOLOv3. it detecting well. but it also searching and matching for other objects. That's why it takes some more time to detect person.
Now I want to create my own data set based on person. I have downloaded 85 thousand cropped images from Google API http://www.rapdataset.com/

But for train these images, it need to be labeled and annotated. thousands of images, how can I do? it takes much time to annotate. Is there any way to annotate these images programmatically like in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this one](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/#how-to-mark-bounded-boxes-of-objects-and-create-annotation-files) to help you, or you have the alternative to use the already annotated set of COCO, and choose persons only of it, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898577/how-to-reduce-number-of-classes-in-yolov3-files).

Comment: i have tried to change these files coco.names. now it has one class = person
and in cfg file i have changed those lines as per the given topic.
Modify your cfg file (e.g. yolov3.cfg), change the 3 classes on line 610, 696, 783 from 80 to 1
Change the 3 filters in cfg file on line 603, 689, 776 from 255 to 18 (derived from (classes+5)x3)
but still its not working. better same result.

Comment: followed this link as you shared.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898577/how-to-reduce-number-of-classes-in-yolov3-files

Comment: @azhar Have you trained it with their dataset?

Comment: no just i have changed those lines from config file. and removed all classed from coco classes file. than had run it.
i did not followed the advance step which was motioned blow of that topic.

Comment: @azhar This will not do it, you have to train it from the beginning.

Comment: ok thanks. i'll just follow the advance concept to train it. thanks for your time.