# OpenCV classifier to detect train (railway transport)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning

Is there any OpenCV classifier which has been trained to detect train on railway?

If there isn't any available, which classifier can be trained using python and OpenCV libraries to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can train a YOLO database to detect trains, you can refer to [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898577/how-to-reduce-number-of-classes-in-yolov3-files) for more detail.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is helpful.