# Create pre-trained weights for detection without darknet / torch

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, yolo

I want to train my data and create a weights file to train my YOLOV3 network.
The objects in my database are not in COCO's classes so I do not want to use their weights file.
I also have a limitation - I can not use darknet and I also prefer not to use the torch library.

The files I have: (according https://github.com/AlexeyAB/Yolo_mark/issues/60#issuecomment-401854885)

1. yolov3-custom.cfg according my classes
2. obj.names with my class's names
3. train.txt + test.txt with list of image's location
4. folder with images+ labels yolo format (object-class, x, y, width, height)
5. obj.data

What can I do?

Comment: Please need answer

Comment: I think you have no option except to use darknet like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898577/how-to-reduce-number-of-classes-in-yolov3-files).

Comment: Why you cannot use darknet? maybe this issue can be fixed so you can train your weights

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel cannot use exe file in my environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I trained my custom according to github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3

Comment: I started training my custom with the pre-trained weights of yolov3.weights. In the beginning the loss was high but after all fixed I trained my custom

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the pre-trained weights on ImageNet if you want to start with pre-trained weights. If you have different classes than the COCO dataset that's no problem. You can define your own classes, and start training with the pre-trained weights. During training, the weights will be updated to detect your custom classes.

You can use these weights for YOLOv3: "https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights"

Comment: I started training my custom with the pre-trained weights of yolov3.weights.
In the beginning the loss was high but after all fixed
I trained my custom according to https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3