# Are there pre-trained weights created only for human detection?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I'm trying to make human detection. I think that YOLOv4 is suitable for that purpose. YOLOv4 uses the COCO dataset. This dataset includes 80 classes. I ran the YOLOv4 code, but it didn't give a good result as well as I wanted. I thought the reason why it didn't give the result I wanted was because of YOLOv4. weights. This weight is created for 80 classes. I tried to train YOLOv4 on a custom dataset to get better results. I used a pre-trained weights-file for training, But this weight is also created for 80 classes. Are there pre-trained weights created only for human detection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can train your database for humans only as detailed in [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898577/how-to-reduce-number-of-classes-in-yolov3-files). I did it for humans and it worked with good efficiency.

Comment: But the question asked for pre-trained weights- they may not have a fast enough computer to produce accurate-enough weights for their use-case