# YOLOv4 detection

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I have trained a YOLOv4 on 6 classes, after seeing the results on videos, I want to delete a class (id=3) as I found it uncessary to my project. Can I use the same model on videos and force it to ignore a class and only detects the other 5 classes without retraining the model on 5 classes.
Thank you

Comment: Maybe this might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57898577/how-to-reduce-number-of-classes-in-yolov3-files

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a trained model will have a final fcn layer aka grid cells, with each grid cell having a `(B x (5 + C))` dimension.

The possible way for you to suppress that class is during post processing where you  can filter out the class based on id.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible on the Neural Network end, maybe you can try to modify it on the application end, something on the lines of:

```
# get detections
# perform NMS
for index in indices:
    if classes[class_ids[index] == "something I want to avoid":
        pass
    else:
        # draw the bounding box
```

**Note: ** The code is loosely based on [this](https://learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-object-detection-using-yolov3-with-opencv-python-c/) example from the Learn OpenCV blog.